# Large desktop display

Tags: mac

Help My window in my mac is too large for the display, I have to move the mouse all the way up to move the entire window down to get to the menu or move the mouse all the way down to get to the dock, not sure how this happened, so frustrated cant get the whole window visible, anyone know? Im on system 10.6.8

Comment: Does it look like it's zoomed in? Try `Option` + `Command` + `8`, this will turn off Smart Zoom if it has accidentally been turned on.

Comment: OMG Thank you so much!!!! I knew it was something I hit on the keyboard, YOU ARE BRILLIANT thanks again!!!! Did I say again thank YOU!! LOLOL

Comment: I've added that as an answer. Feel free to vote and tick it to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like Smart Zoom is turned on.

You can use `Option` + `Command` + `8` to turn it off.

To prevent this from happening again you can disable Smart Zoom by going to **System Preferences** → **Trackpad → Scroll & Zoom** and unchecking the **Smart zoom** gesture.